# First change of css background image, of a div, flickers

Tags: css

I set the background image on a `div` and I set the javascript `mouseover` event to change the background image.  When I mouseover, it changes to the other image but it appears to flicker the first time it is loaded and displayed in the browser. After that the image changes normally (without a flicker).

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what you mean, but [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/DRRnu/386/) of how you can change the image on hover really easy with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preload the image in order to avoid the flicker. Using CSS one could do:

```
body::after {
    content: url(preload-me-1.jpg) url(preload-me-2.jpg);
    display: none;
}
```

But maybe you actually need [image sprites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS) to change background on mouse over, that way you need no preloading.